# Android return null while decoding bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm encoding images, converting them to a Base64 string and saving them in a database, but when I am trying to decode the string and convert it back to bitmap, it returns null:

Here is the code I am using in the decoding process:

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(String encod){
        Bitmap b = null;
        byte[] temp=null;
        temp = Base64.decode(encod, Base64.DEFAULT);
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                temp);
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, o);
        int scale = 1;
        if (o.outHeight > 500 || o.outWidth > 500) {
            scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(500 /
                    (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options o1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o1.inSampleSize = scale;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, o1);
        return b;
    }
```

Can Any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your `ByteArrayInputStream` twice without resetting the buffer position.

Try using `imageStream.reset();` before using `decodeStream` the second time:

```
        imageStream.reset();
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, o1);
```

> ByteArrayInputStream [reset():](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#reset())
>
> Resets the buffer to the marked
>   position.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could just use a simpler method to decode your encoded image like this:

```
byte[] temp = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.length);
```

Comment: I know this way, but I am trying to down size the image also not only decode it.